# Woocommerce : rewrite nested woocommerce product_cat taxonomy slugs to remove parent

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, url-rewriting

I'm facing an issue on removing the parents' slugs from nested `product_cat` terms.

Setup is a basic WPress + WCommerce+ Polylang Pro + Polylang Business pack, just for displaying products, in English and French only (for the moment).

I created all my `product_cat` terms (approx. 100, EN & FR), with three main parents and a bunch of children, either 2 or 3 levels deep. For further upgrade purposes, I made sure to prefix all my nested terms' slugs with their parents' slug, giving something like this:

```
main-term-one
   main-term-one-child-one
      main-term-one-child-one-sub-one
      main-term-one-child-one-sub-two
   main-term-one-second-two
      main-term-one-child-two-sub-one
      main-term-one-child-two-sub-two
main-term-two
   main-term-two-second-one
   main-term-two-second-two
...
```

Doing so, the taxonomy archive pages URLs are `domain.tld/en/product_cat/main-term-one/main-term-one-child-one/main-term-one-child-one-sub-one/`, but they can be reached with `domain.tld/en/product_cat/main-term-one-child-one-sub-one` as well, which is way better IMO. (product pages are not impacted, as the folow the `/shop_base/product_name` rule).

I looked into ways of rewriting programmatically the URL for having the displayed with the "short" version, but I can't find something clear. I'm quite unfamiliar with the way wordpress handles the slug rewriting or even less how to filter that particular taxonomy permalinks for any language given. Found some examples online, but did not seem to work unless having a massive rewrite rules set somewhere in a custom plugin.

From what side should I start looking ?